# How to change the ForeColor of a disabled button

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have this button that launches another program. I disable it after launch to prevent double launch situations. Problem is the ForeColor changes from white to black which doesnt look good against my dark BackColor. How do I make the ForeColor not change when disabling or even change it after disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `EnabledChanged` and `paint` events of the current button. Suppose your button name is `button1`.

```
    private void button1_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button currentButton = (Button)sender;
        button1.ForeColor =  currentButton.Enabled== false ? Color.White : currentButton.ForeColor ;
        button1.BackColor = currentButton.Enabled == false? Color.Black : currentButton.BackColor;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        var solidBrush = new SolidBrush(btn.ForeColor);
        var stringFormat = new StringFormat
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        };
       
        e.Graphics.DrawString(button1.Text, btn.Font, solidBrush, e.ClipRectangle, stringFormat);
        solidBrush.Dispose();
        stringFormat.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: `using (var solidBrush ...) { }` + `using (var stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographics)) { }` (we want to avoid a silly exception to prevent the disposable objects from being disposed here) -- But, you actually don't need any of that since the Button Control uses `TextRenderer.DrawText()` to render its text - inside the `Bounds`, which is already clipped to the transparent Region.

Comment: The button text ends up overlaying like so: https://imgur.com/a/tc9luOV How am I gonna align them together. The text alignment is set to MiddleCenter if that is needed.

Comment: @Jalpesh Please help.

Comment: I think it's not text alignment. It's a placement of button

Comment: @jimi- I will try that and see if it works then will modify the answer