# How to fix alignment of text rendered over a button

Tags: c#, winforms

So in my previous question ([How to change the ForeColor of a disabled button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72644619/how-to-change-the-forecolor-of-a-disabled-button)) I got an answer which rendered new text over the already existing text of the button. Problem is that the text appeared misaligned (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzwIq.jpg). This the code I used:

```
private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            var solidBrush = new SolidBrush(btn.ForeColor);
            var stringFormat = new StringFormat
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far
            };

            e.Graphics.DrawString(button1.Text, btn.Font, solidBrush, e.ClipRectangle, stringFormat);
            solidBrush.Dispose();
            stringFormat.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: I'd avoid the button to bring its own text: just render the text as overimpressed any way.

Comment: That answer is not correct. First thing, you need to use [TextRenderer.DrawText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext) to render the Text, not `Graphics.DrawString()`. Then you need to actively handle the Text that is set to the base class, so you're the only one that draws that text, not also the base class. Otherwise you get that weird effect. -- This is usually done with a Custom Control derived from Button, not using the Paint event handler.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your input, could you please show me how to do that? I am new to WinForms and I don't fully understand what you said.